# C# Unable to pass tag with bound DataGridView control to another method

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tags

In my DataGridView I have a DataGridViewLinkCell and I would like to use Tags to pass an arbitrary string to the DGV's event handler.

This is my code for the LinkCell:

```
DataGridViewLinkCell searchWU = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
searchWU.Value = "Check";
searchWU.LinkVisited = false;
searchWU.Tag = "myTag";
this.hostMgmtDataGridView[colHostViewWUAvil, this.hostMgmtDataGridView.RowCount-2] = searchWU;
```

And then my code for the DGV's event handler:

```
public void hostMgmtDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
DataGridViewLinkCell derp = (DataGridViewLinkCell)sender;
debugLabel1.Text = derp.Tag.ToString();
}
```

The line `DataGridViewLinkCell derp = (DataGridViewLinkCell)sender;` produces the following error:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewLinkCell'.`

If I change it to `DataGridView derp = (DataGridView)sender;` I get a Null Reference with `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I understand the errors, but I don't know how to tease out the LinkCell from it's associated DataGridView.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object sender` is the control, not the selected cell you can find the cell with `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` properties

Try this (Untested)

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        debugLabel1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Tag.ToString();
    }
```